# Maximum planet sizes in Stellaris

Tags: stellaris

what is the maximum planet size in stellaris 2.2.2. I have read somewhere that increasing planet_size over 75 will glitch the planet, and I cant find "regular" max size of planets in galaxy...

Comment: Please specify: are you asking about max pops on a planet or max districts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can have way more pops on your planet then 75.

75 is just the threshold where you get the maximum number of 16 building slots, but that does not limit you from having more pops on your planet.

Also, I don't think there is a "regular max size of planets". You can theoretically have as much pops as you want on a planet. But will get unhappy if you don't provide sufficient housing, which at some point will hinder further growth.

But its possible to provide enough housing to run a stable planet with more than 200 pops. (e.g. 25 city districts x 8 housing each = 216)

Comment: I think he's not asking for population max but size max (the number that feeds into max district count, though confusingly it's not 1:1 the way I would expect)

Answer (score 1):

The standard planet size maximum is 25, just like before. you can increase this by up to 3 (1 from expansion tradition finisher and 2 from the mastery of nature ascension perk). For a total 28 districts maximum on a normal planet.

Machine and hive worlds behave like normal planets. Ecumenopolis planets retain their normal size, but you can build special districts with lots of housing on them (15 for the residential district)

A ringworld works different. It consists of four sections, each with room for 50 sections. I don't know whether the aforementioned perks increase a ring worlds district maximum. Ringworlds use standard districts. So, the maximum is either 4x50 for a normal ringworld or possibly 4x53 with those two perks.

For fun, the maximum housable pop numbers are 168 for a regular planet, 420 for an Ecumenopolis and 318 for a ringworld section. +up to 160, should you choose to fill the planet only with housing buildings.